# Web Api OData: A null value was detected in the items of a collection property value

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I want to return following records from OData:

```
Player
{
    Numbers: [1, null, 3]
}
```

"Numbers" being a collection of nullable items (say IEnumerable). OData has a problem if any of the items in the Numbers collection is null:

A null value was detected in the items of a collection property value; non-streaming instances of collection types do not support null values as items.

Is there a way around it?

I'm using Web Api OData 2.2 (v3)

Thanks,
Stevo

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the `Numbers` property like this:

```
public IEnumerable<int?> Numbers { get; set; }
```

I've tested such POCO definition with some in-memory data:

```
Numbers = new int?[]{1,null,2}
```

and it works fine for a V4 service written using Web API:

```
Numbers: [
    1,
    null,
    2
],
```

I believe it should work also for a V3 service.